# Install4j - ErrorStartingBrowser on Linux

Tags: install4j

I'm using install4j (v10.0.6) to create the installer for an application.

When running the generated installer on a Linux machine, I'm getting the error message defined by the key `ErrorStartingBrowser` when the action "Show File" is called. The param file is a .htm and when I execute the installer through the debug_xxxLinux installer I get no errors, the file is shown on browser correctly in the end. I also have no errors on Windows.

The action is registered on the installation.log file but no error is presented:

```
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.finish.ShowFileAction [ID 240]: Execute action
   Property file: Leiame.htm
   Property rollbackSupported: false
   Execute action successful after 1660 ms
```

Any clue of what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

install4j uses the java.awt.Desktop API to show files. Based on the output in the log file, the call succeeded, otherwise there would be a line `The URI xxx cannot be shown`.

The difference why this works in the debugger installer and not in the non-debugger installer could be that you are using a different JRE in both cases.

Comment: Thanks Ingo, I changed the JRE version to be bundled to a newer one and got it working